# CSS rule works in IE but not in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: html, css

**The typo in my HTML has been corrected. The question is still valid.**

I have this HTML structure:

```
<div id="div1" class="div1">
     <div id="div2" class="div2">
          <h2 class="h2"> Hello </h2>
     </div>
</div>
```

And a CSS that says:

```
.div1.h2 {
    font-size: 1.6em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #808080;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
}
```

With IE the CSS is applied to **h2** but not with Chrome and Firefox

Anything I'm missing?

Comment: Where is `h1` class in your example?

Comment: you don't have an h1 in the div? or is that a typo?

Comment: If IE is applying the style than I must say that IE should be banned by W3C officially...

Comment: Also you're missing a " in div class="div2 and all other classes.

Comment: The was a bug in older IE versions (<=7 IIRC?) whereby it couldn't cope with rules that specify multiple classes on the same element and it would always use the last class in the declaration, so in the example above that would be like writing `.h1` - but who cares about old IE versions? :-P *Edit* [It was in IE6 and lower](http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/multipleclasses.html) which means it definitely doesn't matter

Comment: Given the code you've provided, there is no way that any browser, even IE would apply that CSS to any of those elements. Not even IE8 is that badly malfunctional (there is a possible bug in IE6 that might be at play, but even then it wouldn't do what you're saying). My guess is that there's something more going on than you've posted. Perhaps you should make an example in jsFiddle that demonstrates the problem in action.

Comment: there is no h1 in your html

Comment: Sorry I had a typo assume it is h2 not h1

Comment: but I have such a class name h2

Comment: my CSS is a bit rusty, but doesn't `.div1.h2` only apply to element with both classes, as in `class="div1 h2"`? You probably need a space in the CSS selector, as in `.div1 .h2`

Comment: I guess it would be worth asking at this point what IE version you're using. (and whether it's showing your page in standards mode)

Comment: right, I changed the css to simply h2 and it works, was just surprised the above rule worked in IE and not in other browsers, it is usually the other way around... I'm using IE8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your classes are missing the closing quotes.

[Validate your HTML](http://validator.w3.org/) to prevent further oddities.

**EDIT:** (based on corrected HTML)

Due to inconsistent browser interpretation, `.div1.h2` could mean:

1. All elements with class `div1` *and* class `h2` (which, if the browser is correct, selects **zero** elements), or
2. All elements with class `h2` with *ancestor* elements of class `div1` (which, if the browser behaves, selects your `<h2>`)

I think IE is treating `.div1.h2` as in the latter scenario. Add a space in your selector: `.div1 .h2`.

Comment: You just saw 1 missing close quote?

Comment: Oh lord my eyes are playing tricks. @ArunBertil, three places.

Comment: I wasn't giving the complete html just the relevant snippets, it is properly closed in my html

Comment: @Joly: closing quotation marks are relevant. I thought that might be causing things to display improperly; I didn't mean to offend.

Comment: Cheers, have completed my question now, hope it is clearer now

Answer (score 1):

1. Correct all syntax errors. (missing quotes after class attributes)
2. There is no H1 anywhere

This works

> ```
>  .div1.h2 {
>      font-size: 1.6em;
>      font-weight: bold;
>      color: #808080;
>      margin: 0 0 1em 0; }
> ```

or this

> ```
>  h2, .h2 {
>      font-size: 1.6em;
>      font-weight: bold;
>      color: #808080;
>      margin: 0 0 1em 0; }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a *very* old version of IE (IE6, I think), then there is an IE bug that might be at play here.

The bug in question is that when you have a CSS selector with multiple classes applying to the same element, IE6 will only see the last of those class names.

So `.div1.h2` is seen by IE6 as just `.h2`, whereas other browsers will see `.div.h2`.

The element only has a single class name on it, that being `h2`, so IE6 will match it on the element, but other browsers won't, because they're looking for `class="div2 h2"` -- ie both class names on the same element.

This explains why you may be seeing a difference between browsers.

It doesn't explain why you are using this selector in the first place. Given the HTML code you've quoted, I doubt you actually intended to look for an element with both those classes; you probably want to look for an element with `div2` that has another element with `h2` inside it.

If that's what you wanted, then it is your selector that is incorrect. In order to do that, you need to add a space between the two classes.

```
.div2 .h2 { .... }
     ^
  note the space here
```

Alternatively, you could use a `>` symbol instead of the space, which is a more precise alternative that would suit your HTML code. Unfortunately, if you're using IE6, you can't use `>` as it isn't supported.

Of course, if you're still stuck with IE6, then there will be a whole stack of other things that are broken. My advice is to upgrade your browser like everone else has.

Comment: Also, IE7, IE8 and 1E9 in quirks mode and IE10 in IE5 quirks mode will also faithfully reproduce the IE6 bug, so it's important to have a proper doctype on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone ending up here with an external css sheet not working in Chrome/Firefox but does in IE check encoding of the css and html file. I found Chrome needed css in UTF-8 but firefox also needed the html file in the utf-8.